# How do I add web host's SSL to Cloudflare?

Tags: wordpress, https, cloudflare

I'm stuck with this one and I've searched under Cloudflare's documentation and under [Cloudflare SSL](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcloudflare%5D%20ssl) however I am unable to come up with resolution to my problem.

**Problem:**

Purchased a Domain Validated SSL for a single domain through my webhost.  Under CPanel I can navigate to my file location and I see the directory `ssl` with the childern directories:

```
/certs/file.crt
/csrs/-empty-
/keys/file.key
/private/serveral-files
```

I navigate to `Cloudflare > Crypto > Origin Certificates > Create Certificate`.  I select the radio `I have my own private key and CSR` but when I navigate back to my webhost to look for the CSR under the directory `/csrs` the folder is empty.  When I contact my web host they have no clue what to do and they just apologize and offer a refund on my SSL.

If I do go to my general settings of the WordPress site and change `http://` to `https://` my site goes haywire which after research could be a by-product of what [Mixed Content issue with WordPress, Cloudflare SSL and Genesis Framework](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85706/mixed-content-issue-with-wordpress-cloudflare-ssl-and-genesis-framework) which talks about the issue since I'm calling on several CDNs in my site but I believe that is down the road yet could be related so I thought I would mention it.

Is there another area I'm missing in Cloudflare to add my SSL and am I doing this correcty?  I've never used an SSL with Cloudflare before.

Comment: If your current web host can't help you then your with the wrong host and I wouldn't even go down this road until you have the basic SSL installed on your main site. When you purchase a SSL you should be issued a CA-Bundle, CSR and Private Key... without these you can't use them on any host never-mind cloudflare.

Comment: I agree I am with the wrong web host and looking for an alternative.  How can I validate I have the basic SSL installed then?  Shouldn't there be a file in the `csrs` directory?

Comment: You can validate the issue of SSL using [SSL Labs Testing Tools](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)

Comment: But... if you want to use a 3rd party like cloudflare then you 'must' be issued with the CA Bundle, Key and CSR... without these... you can't. Do yourself a favour and move host. Then purchase your SSL from a reputable SSL vendor such as Comodo SSL, Verisign and so on.

Comment: ok, I figured the issue was with not having the CSR.  I've asked for it but I have to wait 24 hours and its been a week and I'm getting annoyed so I'm looking for a different web host.

Comment: The CSR is the first thing the web host creates without it you can not issue a SSL cert. It's a basically a configuration file that creates the SSL. Most likely they created your SSL and didn't make a backup of the file. They will need to create another CSR file and that means creating a new SSL.

Comment: @SimonHayter can we create a chat to talk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48188/discussion-between-simon-hayter-and-dv).